# A composition of an exponential function with a non-analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> If $f(z)$ is not analytic in $\mathbb C$, then $e^{f(z)}$ is also not analytic in $\mathbb C$. Prove or disprove.

It seems very intuitive that $e^{f(z)}$ will not be analytic in $\mathbb C$ if $f(z)$ is not analytic in $\mathbb C$. Consider $f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then we can write $e^{f(z)} = U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$, where $U(x,y)=e^{u(x,y)}$cos$(v(x,y))$ and $V(x,y)=e^{u(x,y)}$sin$(v(x,y))$.

Assuming that $e^{f(z)}$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$, $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$ should satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. Assuming that the partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, with respect to $x$ and $y$, exist, we get the contradiction that $f(z)$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$.

But are we correct in assuming that the the partial derivatives of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, with respect to $x$ and $y$, will always exist? If not, then what is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: hint: Tale logarithms. Locally this is possible since $e^{f(z)}$ is not vanishing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example.
Let
$f(z) = z$ if $\mathrm{Re}\; z$ is rational and $f(z) = 2\pi i + z$ otherwise.  Then $f(z)$ is continuous nowhere, so certainly not analytic.  But $e^{f(z)} = e^z$ is analytic.

Comment: We could still ask the question when $f(z)$ is continuous.

Comment: If $f(z)$ is continuous but is not analytic then $e^{f(z)}$ can not be analytic. It's because either partial derivatives of $f$ don't exist or if they exist, they are not continuous. Both the cases would render $e^{f(z)}$ to be non-analytic.